# Using django login() without a request object

Tags: ajax, django, json, django-authentication

So I'm looking at the user authentication for django, and since it's turning into this mishmash of ajax-y stuff, I'm unable to send a normal request to my login url, and I'm doing so through json using a jquery ajax method on the client side to post the user data in order to login. So my question is, is there a way to use django's login() function in another way, because my request object is not what is expected, so it won't work. Authenticate works fine, because I just deserialize the username and password, but now I'm stuck on the login() part.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `login()` without a request object doesn't make any sense, because what `login()` does is it ["couples" user to request](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.5/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L75).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you don't get a request object with an Ajax query? You do, of course, and as far as Django's concerned it's exactly the same as the request object you get for any other request.

If you want further help, you're going to have to show some code.